# ROT(n) encoder and decoder, but decoder not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, rot13

I know there are a lot of ways to write a ROT(n) function.
But I don't want to have some table with chars.

So, I've tried to write a simple ROT(n) with decoder, as practice project.
The encode function works fine. But the decoder keeps changing the 'a' into a 'z'.

Could somebody please explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

The (Python3) code below changes everything into lowercase ignoring any special chars.

```
import random
import string

shift = random.randint(1, 20)


# Encoder:
def encode(string):
    coded_string = []
    string = string.lower()
    for c in string:
        if ord(c) >= 97 and ord(c) <= 122:
            c = (ord(c) + shift) % 122
            if c <= 97:
                c += 97
            coded_string.append(chr(c))
            continue
        coded_string.append(c)
    return ''.join(coded_string)


# Decoder:
def decode(string):
    decoded_string = []
    for c in string:
        if ord(c) >= 97 and ord(c) <= 122:
            if ord(c) - shift <= 97:
                c = (ord(c) % 97) + (122 - shift)
                decoded_string.append(chr(c))
                continue
            c = ord(c) - shift
            decoded_string.append(chr(c))
            continue
        decoded_string.append(c)
    return ''.join(decoded_string)


# Test Function:
def tryout(text):
    test = decode(encode(text))
    try:
        assert test == text, 'Iznogoedh!'
    except AssertionError as AE:
        print(AE, '\t', test)
    else:
        print('Yes, good:', '\t', test)


# Random text generator:
def genRandomWord(n):
    random_word = ''
    for i in range(n):
        random_word += random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    return random_word


# Some tests:
print(f'Shift: {shift}')
tryout('pokemon')
tryout("chip 'n dale rescue rangers")
tryout('Ziggy the Vulture or Zurg')
tryout('Fine # (*day%, to* code@ in Pyth0n3!')
tryout(genRandomWord(10))
tryout(genRandomWord(20))
```

Example output:

```
Shift: 7
Yes, good:   pokemon
Iznogoedh!   chip 'n dzle rescue rzngers
Iznogoedh!   ziggy the vulture or zurg
Iznogoedh!   fine # (*dzy%, to* code@ in pyth0n3!
Yes, good:   qrwmfyogjg
Yes, good:   ihrcuvzyznlvghrtnuno
```

but, ignoring the random string tests, I expected:

```
Shift: 7
Yes, good:   pokemon
Yes, good:   chip 'n dale rescue rangers
Yes, good:   ziggy the vulture or zurg
Yes, good:   fine # (*day%, to* code@ in pyth0n3!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your `tryout()` test function forgets to lowercase the input, so it fails for your *Ziggy* example where that actually passes; the corrected test is:

```
# Test Function:
def tryout(text):
    test = decode(encode(text))
    try:
        assert test == text.lower(), 'Iznogoedh!'
    except AssertionError as AE:
        print(AE, '\t', test)
    else:
        print('Yes, good:', '\t', test)
```

The error is in your *decode* function; for a shift of 7, you can see that the encoded letter for `a` -> `h` doesn't map back correctly, while `i` (from `b`), does work:

```
>>> decode('h')
'z'
>>> decode('i')
'b'
```

However, the error goes further; each of the first 7 letters are mistranslated; `g` maps to `y`, `f` maps to `x`, etc. If you use a lower shift that's easy to see:

```
>>> for encoded in 'abcd': print(decode(encoded), end=' ')
... else: print()
...
w x y z
```

Those *should* have mapped back to `x`, `y`, `z` and `a`. So this is a *off-by-one* error, and it is in your test here:

```
if ord(c) - shift <= 97:
```

When `shift` is 3, and `c` is `d`, `ord(c) - shift` is equal to 97, and *should not be adjusted*. Change the `<=` to `<`:

```
if ord(c) - shift < 97:
```

So the fixed `decode()` function then becomes:

```
def decode(string):
    decoded_string = []
    for c in string:
        if ord(c) >= 97 and ord(c) <= 122:
            if ord(c) - shift < 97:
                c = (ord(c) % 97) + (122 - shift)
                decoded_string.append(chr(c))
                continue
            c = ord(c) - shift
            decoded_string.append(chr(c))
            continue
        decoded_string.append(c)
    return ''.join(decoded_string)
```

You may want to learn about the `%` *modulo* operator here, which can help 'wrap around' values to fit within a range, like the range of values for the letters `a` through `z`.

If you take the ASCII codepoint, subtract 97, then use the adjusted value (minus or plus shift, depending on encoding or decoding) and then wrap the resulting value with `% 26`, you always come out on the 'other side' and can add the result back to 97:

```
>>> ord('a') - 97   # a is the 'zeroth' letter in the alphabet, z is the 25th
0
>>> ord('a') - 97 - shift   # shifted by 3 puts it outside the 0 - 25 range
-3
>>> (ord('a') - 97 - shift) % 26  # modulo 26 puts it back in the range, from the end
23
>>> chr((ord('a') - 97 - shift) % 26 + 97)  # add 97 back on to go back to the decoded letter
'x'
```

Another 'trick' is to use a [`bytes` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes), by encoding your input to, say, UTF-8. `bytes` objects are sequences of integers, already processed by the `ord()` function, so to say. Just loop and apply the shift to the bytes in the right range, and append these integers a list. You can then create a new `bytes` object from the list and decode back to a string:

```
def shift_by_n(n, value):
    as_bytes = value.lower().encode('utf8')
    encoded = []
    for v in as_bytes:
        if 97 <= v <= 122:
            v = ((v - 97 + n) % 26) + 97
        encoded.append(v)
    return bytes(encoded).decode('utf8')
```

The above function can work for both *encoding* and *decoding*, simply by passing in the shift as a positive or negative value:

```
def encode(string):
    return shift_by_n(shift, string)

def decode(string):
    return shift_by_n(-shift, string)
```

Finally, rather that test each single letter, you could use the [`str.translate()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) which, given a translation table, makes all replacements for you. You can trivially build a ROT(n) translation table with the [`str.maketrans()` static method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans). Encoding is simply the alphabet mapped to the same alphabet but with `shift` characters from the start taken off and added to the end:

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

def encode(string):
    # take all letters except the first 'shift' characters, and
    # add those letters to the end instead
    rotated = alphabet[shift:] + alphabet[:shift]
    translate_map = str.maketrans(alphabet, rotated)
    return string.lower().translate(translate_map)
```

Decoding uses the same `rotated` string, but the order of the arguments to `str.maketrans()` is swapped:

```
def decode(string):
    # take all letters except the first 'shift' characters, and
    # add those letters to the end instead
    rotated = alphabet[shift:] + alphabet[:shift]
    translate_map = str.maketrans(rotated, alphabet)
    return string.translate(translate_map)
```

Making the above functions work with *uppercase* letters too, only requires that you concatenate the `alphabet.upper()` and `rotated.upper()` results to `alphabet` and `rotated`, respectively, when calling `str.maketrans()` (and remove the `.lower()` call in `encode()`). I'll leave that up to the reader to implement.

Comment: Dear @Martijn Pieters,

Thank you for you reply and explanation!!

This helps a lot.